# What is use of DOIT_SEEK_FILE

Tags: python, doit

I have started to learn about doit automation tool and one thing I stumbled upon is `DOIT_SEEK_FILE` environment variable.

I just want to know what is use of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`doit` command by defaults loads/executes tasks from a `dodo.py` in the current working directory. Sometimes you may wish to just type `doit` from a sub-directory (not where `dodo.py` is located).

`DOIT_SEEK_FILE` will instruct `doit` to recursively look for `dodo.py` in the parent folder if not found in the current working directory.
It has the same effect as command line parameter `--seek-file` as [documented](http://pydoit.org/cmd_run.html#dodo-file).